# Import exports from CJS module as default with @rollup/plugin-commonjs

Tags: javascript, commonjs, rollupjs

I'm using a javascript library that's written for cjs. I am  also using @rollup/plugin-commonjs to transform that library so that I can import it.

```js
// a file I want to import from cjs library
exports.x = 5
```

```js
// rollup.config.js
resolve({
  browser: true,
  dedupe: ['svelte'],
  preferBuiltins: false,
}),
commonjs({
  include: [
    "node_modules/**",
  ],
  dynamicRequireTargets: [  
    "node_modules/cjs-lib/**",
  ],
}),
```

I'm trying to use it in my own app like this.

```js
import lib from "cjs-lib/file.js"
lib.z = function() {
  return lib.x + 5;
}
```

An issue occurs there, with

```js
Uncaught TypeError: lib.x is not a function
```

It seems all the methods defined in the cjs library like `exports.x` is undefined when imported.

Is there anyway to configure `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` such that the `exports` object originally in the cjs library becomes the default export object when its imported in my app?

**Edit:**

To be more concrete, the exact library I'm using is CodeMirror and I'm trying to use its addon, [`runmode/runmode.node.js`](https://www.unpkg.com/browse/codemirror@5.59.0/addon/runmode/runmode.node.js).

```js
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.node';
import 'codemirror/mode/meta';

// Try to extend it here, but findModeByExtension is undefined.
CodeMirror.findMode = function (mode) {
    return mode && (CodeMirror.findModeByExtension(mode) ||
        CodeMirror.findModeByFileName(mode) ||
        CodeMirror.findModeByName(mode) ||
        CodeMirror.findModeByMIME(mode) ||
        CodeMirror.findModeByMode(mode));
};
```

With rollup, the `CodeMirror` object imported is empty, `{}`. But with webpack, the `CodeMirror` object contains all the methods assigned to it with `exports.x = y` and `exports[a] = b` in the `runmode.node.js` file.

**Edit:**

Surprisingly, if the library is imported within `rollup.config.js`, the imported object is not empty and contains all the methods expected.

```js
// rollup.config.js
import * as CodeMirror from "codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.node"
console.log("CodeMirror", CodeMirror);

runmode [Object: null prototype] {
  StringStream: [Getter],
  countColumn: [Getter], ...
```

**Edit**:

As it stands my `rollup.config.js` file has

```js
        commonjs({
            include: "node_modules/**",
            dynamicRequireTargets: ["node_modules/codemirror/**"],
        }),
```

Without including `codemirror` in the `dynamicRequireTargets`, it results in a `require is undefined` error when it comes to these lines within the `runmode.node.js`:

```js
require.cache[require.resolve("../../lib/codemirror")] = require.cache[require.resolve("./runmode.node")];
require.cache[require.resolve("../../addon/runmode/runmode")] = require.cache[require.resolve("./runmode.node")];
```

`dynamicRequireTargets` seems to fix this by wrapping the entire file in this

```js
const commonjsRegister = require('commonjsHelpers.js?commonjsRegister');
commonjsRegister("/$$rollup_base$$/node_modules/codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.node.js", function (module, exports) {
  'use strict';
  // runmode.node.js
}
```

However, this removes all exports and hence the empty import. Is there a way to use `dynamicRequireTargets` and cjs exports together?

Comment: not sure what `dynamicRequireTargets` is for. I think it would work fine as you would remove that configuration

Comment: @tmhao2005 I need to include the cjs-library within dynamicRequireTargets so that rollup resolves the `require` statements that the cjs-library uses internally.

Comment: Without including the library within `dynamicRequireTargets`, the `require.cache[require.resolve` in `runmode.node.js` results in an `require is not defined` error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with CodeMirror using a trick. I realized that with how Rollup is packaging things, all the addons are being processed with the same instance of CodeMirror. So I just need to access that instance.

I patched CodeMirror to create an extra addon file:

```js
// CodeMirror/addon/get_codemirror.js
if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
  module.exports = require("../lib/codemirror");
else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
  define(["../lib/codemirror"], mod);
else // Plain browser env
  return CodeMirror;
```

Now I can just do

```js
import "@my-fork/codemirror/addon/comment/comment";
// ...load more addons

import CodeMirror from "@my-fork/codemirror/addon/get_codemirror";
```

and I get a working CodeMirror with the addons defined.